# Sqlite: Get total top ten score from multiple columns

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table looking like:

```
ID    Task    Score
1     4       2
9     2       0
7     6       1
1     3       1
9     1       2
```

This goes on like this with around 200 rows. Notice how the same ID appears many times but with a different task number. I would like to add all of these scores together for each ID and then take the total value for each ID and output the top 10. I'm looking for a SQL-command to do this, ofcourse i could do this by reading the tables and calculate it in the Python language. But that is not the way i wan't to do it by.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, SUM(score) AS total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Works's perfect, what if i would like to have the ten with the lowest value? I gues that it's the " LIMIT 10 " that et's the top 10?

Comment: You would still use `LIMIT 10` but sorting ascending instead of descending `ORDER BY total ASC`.